# How to install bluetooth in a 05 Lexus ES330?

Tags: electronics, audio, bluetooth, head-unit

I’ve promised my girlfriend that for her birthday I will install a bluetooth system in her car like I have in mine.  The day I got my car I simply had the head unit replaced with a new one with bluetooth.  Her car is a 2005 Lexus ES330 with the non-DIN stock head unit.  Replacing the head unit is not such an appealing option.

What approach would be appropriate in a car like this one?

Comment: Parrot also sells excellent solutions and even come with a screen with physical buttons. If you're not averse to having a separate unit mounted on the dash, that would be my recommended route.

Comment: I have edited my question substantially in the hopes that it will be on-topic.  Please consider removing the hold.